# Rounding up a number

Tags: r

In order to round a number I use this:

```
> number = 12.1
> round(number, digits = 0)
[1] 12
```

How is it possible to make the round to be up. Example the 12.1 become 13. I mean always the round go to the biggest level i.e. even if it is 12.1 or 12.9 become 13.

Comment: Btw, this is **all** covered in `help(round)`.  `ceiling()` is the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ceiling()` command

```
number = 12.1
ceiling(number)
```

This will always round up, just as `floor()` will round down